# What is C#? and the terms associated with it like .net and ASP etc,etc?

Tags: c#

I am having some confusion regarding C# and C#.net and different pl's like asp.net.I mean where they are used and what are their basic application domain.

Comment: There is C# and Visual C# (tm) but no C#.net

Comment: Yeah I don't know exactly what that means, I googled a lot on these topics and I ended being confused , Please provide whatever information you can provide

Comment: This iste is not for basic tutorial/definition questions. Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29

Comment: Can you cut it short I already visited wiki, I need an analogy regarding their application domain, where they are used etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C#:** C Sharp is an object-oriented programming language created by Microsoft. In short, it is the language, it includes the syntax you see, but not the methods, which are from the .NET framework.

C# is the language that you will write in, but .NET and ASP.NET are frameworks that will depend on what you want to *do* with C#.

**.NET:**

> .NET Framework is a software framework developed by Microsoft that
>   runs primarily on Microsoft Windows. It includes a large library and
>   provides language interoperability (each language can use code written
>   in other languages) across several programming languages. (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework))

In short, it is a very useful set of classes used across applications built in C#.

**ASP .NET:**

> ASP.NET is a server-side Web application framework designed for Web
>   development to produce dynamic Web pages. It was developed by
>   Microsoft to allow programmers to build dynamic web sites, web
>   applications and web services.  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET))

In short, it is a server-side web development framework that can be used in C# code.

Comment: So which one should I learn first

Comment: Go with C#, as it is what you will _write in_, .NET is what your code will _use_, and ASP is what you will want to look into for _web development_.

Comment: You can't (usefully) learn .NET without also learning either C# or VB.NET or ASP.NET, and you can't (usefully) learn any of them without learning about .NET. Whether to choose C# or ASP.NET depends on what you want to do with it, and that's what @Cyral's wikipedia extracts (above) will help you to do.

Comment: What @ClickRick said, there is no use learning .NET or ASP.NET when you have nothing to write it in. They are simply extensions to C#

Comment: Thanks to both of you finally I got it,now I will clearly think what I have to persue and I will act accordingly, btw I want to go in the gaming field , i.e. make games and all that crazy stuff, any ideas how to prepare for it I mean the programming part and whatever useful information you can provide

Comment: As far as C#, that is a tough one, the XNA framework is pretty much dead, and it _was_ the most popular one. Just google around and see what you can find.

Comment: I know about the XNA one actually I was going to prepare for it 6-7 months ago but as I found out about it it was not much used as it was earlier so, thanks for that I'll see what I can find .

Answer (score 0):

Read the guidelines for Microsoft .net framework here:

http://www.microsoft.com/net/nettechnologyguidance

Download the `The .NET Technology Guide for Business Applications` from there, it describes all microsoft .net technologies and their applications.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a program, we need a technology and to write a program we need a language.

To create a windows forms application, language is **C#** and Technology is **Windows Forms**

To create a web application, language is **C#** and Technology is **ASP.Net**

To create a Services, language is **C#** and Technology is **WCF**

**VB** is another language. We can use that instead of **C#**

All these technologies and languages are collectively called as .Net Framework.